# Can't Change iMac Screen Brightness, Connected to PC via DisplayPort; Backlight Folder Empty

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness, backlight

I've installed Ubuntu Studio Xenial 16.04.1 on my PC with i7 6800k and GTX 970, connected to my iMac 11,3 (which I'm using as a monitor) via DisplayPort.I'm not able to change the backlight levels of my display; in fact, my /sys/class/backlight is completely empty.

When I run `lshw -c video`, I get:

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:53 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fb000000-fb07ffff
```

If I open Software & Updates and go to the Additional Drivers tab, under the `NVIDIA Corporation:GM204[GeForce GTX 970]`, is says I'm `Using NVIDIA binary driver-version 367.57 from nvidia-367 (proprietary, tested)`.

For the device `Unknown: Unknown`, it says I'm `Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode(proprietary)` instead of `Do not use the device`.

In case it helps, I've located the `brightness` and `max_brightness` files in another directory: `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:06:00.0/leds/phy0-led/`

How can I setup my system so that I can change my iMac screen brightness using my apple keyboard shortcuts just as I can volume?

Comment: It is not possible to change backlight on the external device. Unless some special way to send commands through the Display port. I do not think there is an easy solution for that.

Comment: Really? So everyone who uses external monitors have to use physical controls on the actual monitor, and can't change from within the OS? Even on Windows? I don't get how I can control my iMac's speaker volume levels through DisplayPort but not display backlight levels.

Comment: Some monitor vendors provide some utilities to control the backlight of their monitors, some don't. There is no generic way to control backlight of external monitors.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer :/. Does this mean my iMac display will be using full backlight levels (and draw full power) as long as it's in use by my pc?

Comment: I think you can adjust it in your iMac.

Comment: Wow, you know what? Until now, I never thought of plugging my keyboard into my iMac while it's in Targeted Display Mode and change the brightness. It works! Thanks very much!! Unfortunately I still can't use f.lux to change color temperatures for working at night. Does ridshift use software, and work on external monitors?